# Time period diagram (bar chart) - what is it's real name?

Tags: visualization

I want to make a diagram like this to display the career spans of several soccer players one below the next:

[image: Career span diagram]

I know it's basically a bar chart, but I was hoping this has a more specific name, because I want to search the web to find out whether d3.js can easily render one.

Comment: I provided an answer (not sure if it's exactly what you're looking for), but please keep in mind that this isn't really a Math question as such.

Comment: What's the right place to post this question? I'll move it there if I know where to post. I didn't think it was directly programming related enough for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Maybe this: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/data-visualization ? I don't know if it's a perfect fit, but it looks like a good place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest I can think of is a [Gantt Chart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gantt_chart), but that's more often used for project analysis.

(and by the way, this isn't really math).